# Can I parse a text value from a specific column in a query (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, select, parse

I was playing around with Sakila and I ran across the actor_info view and one of its columns is film_info which is a detail of all the movies one actor has worked in. For example a query would be:

```
select * from actor_info;
# actor_id | first_name | last_name | film_info
    1      | PENELOPE   |   GUINESS |  Animation: ANACONDA CONFESSIONS; Children: LANGUAGE COWBOY; Classics: COLOR PHILADELPHIA, WESTWARD SEABISCUIT; Comedy: VERTIGO NORTHWEST; Documentary: ACADEMY DINOSAUR; Family: KING EVOLUTION, SPLASH GUMP; Foreign: MULHOLLAND BEAST; Games: BULWORTH COMMANDMENTS, HUMAN GRAFFITI; Horror: ELEPHANT TROJAN, LADY STAGE, RULES HUMAN; Music: WIZARD COLDBLOODED; New: ANGELS LIFE, OKLAHOMA JUMANJI; Sci-Fi: CHEAPER CLYDE; Sports: GLEAMING JAWBREAKER
```

So I'd like to make a selection of actors who have worked in documentaries or animation but i don't know if this is possible. Sorry if the question is too basic. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to get `field_name` and `last_name` of rows where `film_info` starts with, or contains, "Animation or Documentary"?

Comment: When `INSERTing`, pick out selected fields and make them into columns.  Then put the rest (or all) into `film_info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## WITHOUT INDEXING

```
SELECT * FROM actor_info
WHERE film_info LIKE '%Animation%' OR film_info LIKE '%Documentary%';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM actor_info
WHERE LOCATE('Animation',film_info)>0
OR LOCATE('Documentary',film_info)>0;
```

## WITH INDEXING

Create a FULLTEXT index on `film_info`

```
ALTER TABLE actor_info ADD FULLTEXT (film_info);
```

Query using the `FULLTEXT` index

```
SELECT * FROM actor_info
WHERE MATCH (film_info) AGAINST ('+Animation*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION
SELECT * FROM actor_info
WHERE MATCH (film_info) AGAINST ('+Documentary*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Thanks! What I wonder too is if the content of the film_info column can be filtered so it can show that Penelope worked in Anaconda Confessions without showing the rest.